# Getting and Setting the path

Tags: c, shell, path, get, set

I've been giving the task of writing a simple shell, I've managed to get some really basic functionality however for one of the stages it's asking me to get and set the environment. This is the details of the task.

Stage 4: Getting and setting the path – 10 marks

Keep original path

The reason this is necessary is because we would like to restore the path to what was originally on exiting the shell. This is important because any changes you do to the shell’s environment (i.e. setenv() function above), does not only affect the shell itself but also any other program that will be executed from the same terminal afterwards. For this reason, it is a good idea to put things back the way they were on exit.

A single string will be enough to keep the original path.

Saving the path should be the first thing your shell does when it starts up.

Print and change the path – built-in commands

From a C program we can access the environment using the getenv() function and we can change the environment using the setenv() function. If you look at the manual pages for setenv(), you will find how it works (i.e. parameters needed and return values) as well as what you need to include to use it.

getpath – print system path & setpath – set system path

These two commands are about the environment parameter PATH. The first just gets and prints its value, while the second takes a path (string of colon separated list of directories) as a parameter and makes it the value of PATH. You can getenv() and setenv() respectively for this purpose.

Restore path

You just change the PATH environment parameter to its original value (i.e. the one you saved at the start up of the shell).

Restoring the path should the last thing your shell does before it exits.

Stage 4: Testing

First, make sure that all the tests you carried out for stage 3 still work. Be careful though, as we are now changing the path this will affect the execution of external programs.

To check the additional functionality, you should start by checking that the save and restore of the path work. A good idea here is to print the path when you save it at the beginning of the execution of the shell and then again when you exit at the end. In both cases the printed path should be exactly the same!

Following that you should check that when getpath is called you print the current path, which should be the same as the original one.

Then you should focus on testing setpath. First, setpath the path to a new value and test that getpath prints it, then try also to see how changing the path really affects the execution of external commands (e.g. set the path to only ‘.’ and try ‘ls’ or try the shell itself, etc).

This is my code:

```
/* S.NO:201148541 Simple Shell Example
Completed upto Stage 3 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARR_SIZE 1<<16

void parse_args(char *buffer, char** args, 
                size_t args_size, size_t *nargs)
{
    char *buf_args[args_size]; 
    char **cp;
    char *wbuf;
    size_t i, j;

    wbuf=buffer;
    buf_args[0]=buffer; 
    args[0] =buffer;

    for(cp=buf_args; (*cp=strsep(&wbuf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*cp != '\0') && (++cp >= &buf_args[args_size]))
            break;
    }

    for (j=i=0; buf_args[i]!=NULL; i++){
        if(strlen(buf_args[i])>0)
            args[j++]=buf_args[i];
    }

    *nargs=j;
    args[j]=NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *args[ARR_SIZE];
    int *ret_status;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t pid;

    char curDir[100];


    while(1){
        getcwd(curDir, 100);
        printf("%s->", curDir);
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        parse_args(buffer, args, ARR_SIZE, &nargs); 

        if (nargs==0) continue;
         if(strcmp(args[0], "cd") == 0){
            chdir(args[1]);

        }
        else if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit" )) exit(0);       
        pid = fork();
        if (pid){
            pid = wait(ret_status);
            printf("finished\n", pid);
        }
         else {

            if( execvp(args[0], args)) {
                puts(strerror(errno));
                exit(127);
            }
        }
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

I'm really at a loss and any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is your problem?

Comment: I trying to implement 2 functions in order to get the environment PATH and set the environment, I'm really unsure how I should go about this, from my assignment it states that using the getenv and setenv functions I can do this, however Im not sure how to start this. For example is it just a function I write then call it when a specific input is taken at the user input? (like I have done for the exit and cd commands)

Comment: Is that code snippet written by you or given in the assignment? It contains no path setting code what so ever!

Answer (score 1):

Given that we don't know what your previous steps are, and going by the advice

> Then you should focus on testing setpath. First, setpath the path to a
>   new value and test that getpath prints it, then try also to see how
>   changing the path really affects the execution of external commands
>   (e.g. set the path to only ‘.’ and try ‘ls’ or try the shell itself,
>   etc).

You can do like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *path, *old, *tobeSet;
    path = malloc(1024);
    path = getenv("PATH");
    old = malloc(strlen(path));
    tobeSet = malloc(10); // just to be safe
    strcpy(tobeSet,".");
    if(setenv("PATH",tobeSet,1)!=0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't set path\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nPATH::\t%s\n",path);
    printf("\n\nNewPath::\t%s\n",tobeSet);
    if(setenv("PATH",path,1)!=0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't restore path\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n\nOld path ::\t%s\n",path);
    free(path);
    free(old);
    free(tobeSet);
    return 0;
}
```